# Image distortion when user clicks UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I'm seeing an odd thing occur when I press the UIButton with a background image:
http://cl.ly/9LM0

Here is the code where I setup the button:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.categoryItem.label ofType:@"jpg"];
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: path];

UIButton *imageBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
imageBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 235);
[imageBtn setImage:theImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[imageBtn.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

[imageBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onImageClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:imageBtn];
```

EDIT: I apologize for not clarifying the oddity that I'm seeing—I was in a rush getting off the train :-P

The issue is that as the user is clicking the UIButton with a background image, the image stretches to the width of the screen. It's fine in it's normal state, but the click state is where I'm seeing the distortion which you can see in the screen recording that I referred to above.

Thanks!

Comment: chage to [imageBtn.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

Comment: please share with us which site did u use for tiny url.it really great to explain .can u please share with us.thanks.

Comment: @Vijay, that is not the effect I'm looking for. Your solution makes my image fill all the time. I want to keep the "fit" and make it so the click does not cause the image to fill, but keeps fit as well.

Comment: Oh yeah and the url comes from an app called http://getcloudapp.com/

Comment: i cant understand what do u want and please paste here ur onImageClick method code

Comment: hi please reply . i can anwer u.

Comment: Ok I provided some additional clarification of the issue at hand.